# Making custom Excel VBA function faster

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have a custom function that is used to count or sum how many colored cells I have. This is the function:

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)

    Application.Volatile (True)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    If SUM = True Then
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
            End If
        Next rCell
    Else
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

ColorFunction = vResult

End Function
```

---

It is invoked by inputting the following function:

```
=colorfunction($A$1,A2:C2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=colorfunction($A$1,A2:C2,TRUE)
```

Where:

- A1 = Cell with background color to be checked
- A2:C2 = Range to be counted
- FALSE/TRUE = Count or Sum

---

My question is: **Is there anything I can do to the VBA to speed up this function?**

I have tried to experiment with the `WorksheetFunction` part but was not able to find a syntax that worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: Remove `Application.Volatile` because your function is not volatile. Make all arguments `ByVal`. Replace `WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)` with `vResult + rCell.Value`, unless you are using `SUM` to silently ignore non-numeric values.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the tips. If I remove `Application.Volatile` the function does not calculate unless I force it. Your `WorksheetFunction...` appears to have made some impact. Can you explain your `ByVal` comment? Thank you

Comment: I have to force recalculation even when `Application.Volatile (True)` is included except when last parameter is `TRUE`. Then, either way recalculates.

Comment: @redditor With `Volatile` the function recalculates on each sheet change anywhere in Excel, as opposed to only when there is a change in its arguments. However a color change is not a part of this, your function will not reevaluate when you change a cell's color, even with `Volatile`. `ByVal` should be used whenever you don't need `ByRef`, and you don't, so use `ByVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Function ColorFunction2(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, _
                        Optional pSUM As Boolean) As Variant
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult As Variant, vTmp As Variant ' for intermediate calcs, _
                                          for clear vision of logic, _
                                          for not doubling code
    Application.Volatile (True)

    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    For Each rCell In rRange.Cells ' expicit .Cells
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            Select Case pSUM ' SUM is reserved word
                Case True:  vTmp = rCell.Value ' out of sheet functions calling
                Case False: vTmp = 1
        ' change True-False sequence according to real probability they occures
            End Select
        End If
        vResult = vResult + vTmp
    Next ' rCell ' No need

    ColorFunction2 = vResult
End Function
```

Added expicit  "As Variant"

Comment: SUM is not a reserved word. Explicit `As Variant` is a matter of coding style, has no effect on performance. Moving the `select case` inside the loop makes the condition evaluate each time instead of once in advance. Over all, that's making code pretty to print rather than better to execute.

Comment: > _SUM is not a reserved word_  
Yeah :) However, let assume it so. It used very often.  
  
> _Moving the select case ...  _  
Yes. I see. It's my oversight. I was so hurry of my own business, that I viewed only in a half-eye and the W-Sheet SUM caughts my eye only. I'll check speed decreasing degree of this.